# how can i send notification from flutter-web to flutter-application?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had a project from two application(flutter application) and three flutter-web on the same firebase i want to send notification from the web to the application.

i searched alot for this and i cant find any answer or solution for this case.

I had a project from two application(flutter application) and three flutter-web on the same firebase i want to send notification from the web to the application.

i searched alot for this and i cant find any answer or solution for this case.

Comment: you need to store firebase token of apps somewhere and use HTTP json requests to do that.

Comment: can you tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I hope you understand that we can't give you the finish solution here. I would recommend to you to go trough this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging).

What we can do is to explain it a little bit. For your solution I would recommend to use FCM. And how they work is that:

- you use the Firebase SDK to receive a `token` from the client device.
- you store that `token` on one of the Firebase databases
- when sending a push notification to a device you would need to do it from the Firebase Cloud Functions and use that token to send the message to it. When you do that the device from witch the token is will get the message.

It doesn't matter what platform the device is (web, ios or android). All of them can receive Push Messages (in Web most of them but nor 100% all).

From your use case I would not recommend to use `topics`. You want to send messages from device to device and therefore the `tokens` are the best solution for it.